# Getting Exception While uploading file on media services azure

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I want uploading file on media services. When I upload file it gives exception after some time. 
here is the exception

```
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MediaServices.Client.AssetFileData.Upload(String path)
at OnDemandEncoding.Models.Azure.UploadFile(String filePath) in C:\Users\Usman Bajwa\Desktop\Cloud Tech\OnDemandEncoding\OnDemandEncoding\Models\Azure.cs:line 49
```

Here is my uploading code.

```
CloudMediaContext _context = GetContext();

string assetName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(filePath);
IAsset Asset = _context.Assets.Create(assetName, AssetCreationOptions.None);
Console.Error.Write("Asset Created");
IAssetFile assetFile = Asset.AssetFiles.Create(Path.GetFileName(filePath));
Console.Error.Write(assetFile.Name);
var policy = _context.AccessPolicies.Create(
        assetName,
        TimeSpan.FromDays(20),
        AccessPermissions.Write | AccessPermissions.List);
ILocator locator = _context.Locators.CreateLocator(LocatorType.Sas, Asset, policy);
Console.Error.Write(assetFile.Name);
Console.Error.Write("Uploading File");

assetFile.Upload(filePath);      // Getting Exception at this line

locator.Delete();
policy.Delete();


return assetId = assetFile.Asset.Id;
```

Comment: Did you resolve this upload issue Muhammad? Was it network related?

Comment: if you can provide the exception message (you've only provided the stack trace) you will get higher chances to get help there...

Comment: I resolved that error.